# Participle or Gerund?

Tags: gerunds, participles

Is “ferrying” in the following passage a gerund or a present participle?

> In March 2016, Zipline, a U.S. startup partnered with the Rwandan government to launch the world’s first commercial drone delivery service, ferrying vital medical supplies to far-flung hospitals by air. Since October of that year, the company has dispatched more than 7,000 units of blood products to 21 hospitals, …
> (TIME, May 31, 2018; https://time.com/longform/ziplines-drones-are-saving-lives/ )

If it is a participle, I think, it will make up a reduced participle clause, with the subject being “the world’s first commercial drone delivery service”. In which case, the clause may be rewritten as “which ferries vital medical supplies …”; present tense “ferries” is made necessary by the next sentence saying the service is still going on; however, tense disagreement between “ferries” and the main clause verb “partnered” concerns me.

Or, “ferrying” is a gerund?

Comment: The writer wrote ferrying precisely to avoid *which ferries*, which is heavy. and breaks up the flow of the sentence. The writer also could have said: *to ferry vital medical supplies to*[wherever]. You can always form sentences from this participles: Ferrying medical supplies to x is dangerous.

Comment: *Ferrying* in your quote acts as a participle verb, not a gerundy noun.

Comment: Two sentences with the same **subject** can be combined by reducing one sentence to a participle clause. So: ***Zipline** partnered with the Rwandan government to launch [a] drone delivery service.* + ***Zipline** ferried vital medical supplies to far-flung hospitals by air.* = ***Zipline** partnered with the Rwandan government to launch [a] drone delivery service, ferrying vital medical supplies to far-flung hospitals by air.*  (*Ferrying* is a participle.)

Comment: It does not matter what it is. The fact is that it avoids which ferries.

Comment: @Lambie: No — there is no nonrestrictive reduced relative clause involved here.

Comment: "Ferrying" is a present participle. _Ferrying vital medical supplies to far-flung hospitals by air_ is certainly an adjunct, though I’m not sure how to describe the subtype of adjunct that it is.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I really dislike it when people ascribe things to me I did not say. I said the participle **avoids** using "which will ferry". Forgot the will. OR  *Zipline, a U.S. startup partnered with the Rwandan government to launch the world’s first commercial drone delivery service **and ferry** vital medical supplies to far-flung hospitals by air.*  Also, a to-infinitive would not work, I was mistaken.

Comment: Certainly it is a participial verb form: it ends in the _-ing_ suffix. It's transitive because it has a direct object, and it's missing a subject. It can't be a gerund, though, because it's not acting like a noun -- it's not a subject or object -- but rather like an extra verb with extra information, arranged neatly in a verb phrase. And the identity of the missing subject is a bit unclear -- it could be the startup, the Rwandan government, or the service that was delivering stuff, or some combination. Good place for a participle with an ambiguous  subject.